# Will it ever be possible for $/ to support regexes?

Tags: perl

To quote [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> ... the value of `$/` is a string, not a regex. `awk` has to be better for something. :-)

It is not difficult to think of situations where such a feature would be useful - parsing files with variable-length records is a classic use case which I encounter many times.

So far I have never had trouble loading the entire file into memory and do a :

```
my @records = split /my_regex/, <> ;
```

but for obvious reasons this technique cannot be used in situations where available memory is inadequate. In fact, many a time there is no need for all records to be stored at the same time.

Which brings me back to `$/`.

I find it odd that the language has not provisioned regex support for `$/`. Was this done by design? Is it simply impossible to implement? What other workarounds exist that can be considered as best practices in the absence of what would be a nifty feature?

Comment: [`Acme::InputRecordSeparatorIsRegexp`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Acme::InputRecordSeparatorIsRegexp)

Comment: @mob : You couldn't let awk get away with it, now, could you? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't make much sense to even try. Far too often, you wouldn't be able to tell if you've reached the end of the line without reading past its end. That could be very bad in interactive situations.

For example, let's say you have the following program:

```
local $/ = qr/\n|\r\n?/;  # Handle Windows, Unix and old MacOS line endings.
while (1) {
   print "Please enter a command: ";
   my $cmd = <>;
   $cmd =~ s{$/\z}{};
   process($cmd);
}
```

Looks pretty straightforward, right? In fact, supporting `qr/\n|\r\n?/` is probably the number one reason for this request. Well, even that simple code is severely flawed. Let's say I use MacOS line endings (CR, ^M, \r)

```
 $ processor
 Please enter a command: foo^M
 [hangs]
```

The program hangs because it can't tell whether I gave it a MacOS line ending (CR, ^M, \r) or a Windows line ending (CRLF, ^M^J, \r\n) until another character is typed.

I'd have to enter a second command to process the first, a third command to process the second, etc. It just makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

One of the biggest problems I can see is that supporting a regex record separator *in general* requires the entire contents of the file to be scanned.

Suppose, for instance, that, for whatever reason, you had specified a separator of `/\n[^X]+\z/`. The whole file would need to be read to check whether there were any `X` characters after each newline.

So there are three options that I can think of:

- Buffering the whole file just to scan for record separators
- Implementing regular expressions on a "paged" string so that the file can be read in parts
- Implementing a subset of the standard regular expressions for use as record separators

None of these is a particularly attractive prospect from the implementation point of view, and I can see that I would avoid doing it if possible, especially as the first option is available to the Perl coder through the use of `split`.

Comment: The fact that people could provide regexes that make no sense is not a reason not to support regexes.

Comment: Re "Buffering the whole file just to scan for record separators", This is already the case (with `local $/;` and with a file that doesn't contain `$/`)

Answer (score 3):

The (backtracking) implementation of the Perl regex engine is fundamentally incompatible with the usage as a line ending. Part of this problem is that you don't want to rerun the whole regex when the next character is read. For example, take the regex

```
$/ = qr/ A \w*? B | XY/;
```

And the data stream

```
f o o A 1 2 X Y B b a r
```

So when should the `readline` return? If we do incremental matching, we might get something like

```
f o o A 1 2 X Y B b a r
      A\w\w\w\w B

#=> fooA12XYB
```

If we re-run the whole regex at each position, we get

```
f o o A 1 2 X Y B b a r

      A *FAIL
      *FAIL

      A\w *FAIL
      *FAIL

      A\w\w *FAIL
      *FAIL

      A\w\w\w *FAIL
            X *FAIL

      A\w\w\w\w *FAIL
            X Y

#=> fooA12XY
```

In other words, alternations (with precedence) make this matching complicated. If the regex engine were not backtracking (but would rather run as a table parser or state machine), there would be no difference between rerunning the whole regex, or doing incremental matching. However, regex engines where this is possible are less expressive than Perl regexes.

Another problem would be the line ending

```
$/ = qr/ .+ /xs;
```

Should reading such a “line” return just the next character (because the regex is already satisfied after one character), or the whole file (because `.*` wants to match as much as possible)? Or should the rest of the internal buffer be returned, whatever it currently contains?

To use regexes for line endings, these ambiguities have to be adressed, and additional limitations would have to be imposed (e.g. only regular languages allowed).

Comment: I see. This also answers the follow-up question of why awk can do it and Perl can't.

Comment: The fact that you can use inefficient regexes is not a very convincing reason to not support them.

Comment: There's no issue with `$/ = qr/ .+ /xs;` (except that it would be dumb to do). You have to keep reading, even without regex. e.g. Consider `$/ = "\r\n";` or `$/ = $mime_sep;`.

Comment: @ikegami My main argument is that there is a lot of ambiguity to be defined, and that resolving such ambiguities does not translate well to Perl regexes. Other regex dialects are reestricted enough to allow this usage. Of course, your answer has a far more elegant argument.

Comment: And I say it's crystal clear how it's defined. No ambiguities at all. Of course, as I pointed in my answer, there are major problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

[Perl6::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl6%3a%3aSlurp) looks like a possible workaraound:

> You can set the input record separator ({ irs => $your_irs_here}) for
>   the input operation. The separator can be specified as a string or a
>   regex.

Comment: From the docs: "Note that an explicit input record separator has no input-terminating effect in a scalar context; slurp always reads in the entire input stream, whatever the 'irs' value"

Comment: ... so this is simply loading the whole file in memory, then separating