# Perl "=+\n" as $/ separator

Tags: perl

Sorry for a stupid question, but I'm a beginner, so I can't sort out this problem.

I work with files where chunks of data are divided by lines of consecutive `=` signs of different length, followed by `\n`. I want to read these chunks as separate records, using `$/ = "=+\n";` But it doesn't detect the `===` separator.

So my code is:

```
$ cat prog1 
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.22;
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = "=+\n";
$\="+++\n";

while (<>){
  chomp;
  print;
}
```

My data:

```
$ cat data1 
line1
line2
===
line4
line5
```

My output:

```
$ ./prog1 data1 
line1
line2
===
line4
line5
+++
```

Comment: [Related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19159052/133939)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted to know, I'll read the A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$/` doesn't support regular expressions. You'll need to use `===\n`.

You can use a regex to pseudo-`chomp` using a regex though.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;


$/ = "=\n";
$\="+++\n";

while (<>){
  s/^=+\n\z//gm;
  print;
}
```

See: [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> the value of $/ is a string, not a regex.

Comment: Thanks! 
That's a pity, I supposed it would work as in awk.

Probably it would be easier to read the whole file in a variable and then split it using `"=+\n"` as a separator.

Comment: @evb depends on how big the file is.

Comment: You can always read line by line, to assemble a buffer and 'process' it (and clear it) when you hit your regex. But this approach seemed to do what you wanted, and was simpler.

Comment: Yes, of course, it solves the problem, thanks! Though I wonder why Perl can't work with regex as $/.

Comment: Because that's what the design says :). If I had to guess, it'll be because some regex patterns make life _very_ difficult when trying to decide how many bytes to read, and getting into catestrophic backtracking after each byte could get expensive fast.

Comment: [`Acme::InputRecordSeparatorIsRegexp`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Acme::InputRecordSeparatorIsRegexp)?

Answer (score 2):

If the file is short enough, load it into memory and split on whatever end-of-record indicator you want:

```
local $/;
my @lines = split /=+\n|\++\n/, <>;
foreach my $line (@lines) { ... }
```

If it is important what the record separator was (say, if you need to distinguish records that end with `===\n` from records that end with `+++\n`), capture the record separator

```
local $/;
my @lines = split /(=+\n|\++\n)/, <>;
while (my $line = shift @lines) {
    my $record_separator = shift @lines;
    ...
}
```